# AWS CodeDeploy and git rm

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have removed some files from my git repo and pushed the changes and deployed using AWS CodeDeploy. When I logged into the EC2 instance, there are new files corresponding to the latest commit but the deleted files still exist. Is this behaviour normal?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. The agent should clean up your old deployment artifacts before deploying the new one.

So you should not see old files. I would suggest to double check the commit used for deployment. If all is right there, then the agent logs in /var/log/aws/codedeploy/codedeploy-agent.log might shed some light.

Thanks,
Amartya